# Why is my function undefined?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript. I have coded the following:

```
function Vec2(x_,y_)
{
    this.x = x_;
    this.y = y_;
}
```

Later in the file I create a function like this:

```
// Init game field array
var initGameField = function () {
    var screenCenter = vec2(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
    var index = 0;

    // Init gamefieldArray
    for(var y = 0; y < maxVerticalBubbles; y++)
    {
        if(y%2)
        {
            for(var x = 0; x < maxHorizontalBubbles - 1; x++)
            {
                var initPoint = vec2(cellSize / 2 + (screenCenter.x - ((maxVerticalBubbles - 1) * cellSize / 2)) + (x * cellSize), 
                                 canvas.height / 2 + (cellSize / 2) + y * cellSize / 1.1);

                gameFieldArray[index] = initPoint;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for(var x = 0; x < maxHorizontalBubbles; x++)
        {
                var initPoint = vec2(cellSize / 2 + (screenCenter.x - (maxVerticalBubbles * cellSize / 2)) + (x * cellSize), 
                                 canvas.height / 2 + (cellSize / 2) + y * cellSize / 1.1);

                gameFieldArray[index] = initPoint;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to run the initGameField function at the end of the javascript -file I get errors on "vec2 not defined" inside "initGameField"... How should this be done the right way? Why isn't the function vec2 recognized since it has been introduced before initGameField -function and before running initGameField -function?

Answer (score 8):

Javascript is case-sensitive, your function is defined as **Vec2** but you're trying to invoke it using **vec2**

Also make sure that you create a new instance by using the 'new' keyword.

```
var initPoint = new Vec2(cellSize / 2 + (screenCenter.x - ((maxVerticalBubbles - 1) * cellSize / 2)) + (x * cellSize), 
                             canvas.height / 2 + (cellSize / 2) + y * cellSize / 1.1);
```

Comment: He must construct it, not just invoke. It should be `var screenCenter = new Vec2(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);`